# How to get following Markov chain?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A fair die is rolled repeatedly and ask for the following transition matrix.

> (1) the largest number $X_n$ shown up to the nth roll.

For this question, I know the answer is 
$$P_{ij}=\frac{i}{6}, j=i \text{ and } P_{ij}=\frac{1}{6}, j>i$$

But how to get it? Why $j=i$ the probability is $i/6$?

> (2) At the time $n$, the time $T_n$ since the most recent six. How to get $P_{ij}$?

Is it a Markov chain? How to understand it?

> (3) At the time $n$, the time $T_n$ until the next six. How to get $P_{ij}$?

I know that if $j>i$ then $P_{ij}=(5/6)^{j-1}(1/6)$ which is a geometry process. But how the other cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

(1) You have already obtain $i$ as the largest number. To stay at the same state, you can get any of the $i$ smallest value.

(2) Suppose at time $n$, you are at state $i$. It can either go to state $i+1$ or go to state $0$. To go to state $0$, you toss a $6$.

(3) The time until the next $6$ should be decreasing by $1$ unit with probability $1$ if your current state it not $0$.  If your current state is $0$, then the transition probabiity follows geometric distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I still have a question. For (1), how to get $P_{ij}=1/6$ for $i<j\leq 6$?

Comment: you have to toss $j$ to reach state $j$.